# Problemas traduciendo párrafos con salto de líneas en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy traduciendo una Web, Laravel tiene una función para hacerlo con JSON, se crea un documento JSON y se guarda en el directorio Lang que se encuentra dentro del directorio Resources, ejemplo:

```
"Sobre Nosotros": "About Us",
"Servicios": "Services",
"Testimonios": "Testimonials",
"Contacto": "Contact",
```

Luego en la vista se recibe con:

```
{{ __('Sobre Nosotros') }},  {{ __('Servicios') }},  {{ __('Testimonios') }} y ,  {{ __('Contacto') }}
```

y funciona bien, el problema se presenta cuando hay un párrafo largo y que tenga un salto de línea, en la vista se muestra así para mostrarlo con el formato correspondiente:

```
{!! __(nl2br($content->text)) !!}
```

que mostraría algo así, ya que en el campo de la base de datos está guardado con el salto de línea:

Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.

No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.

Por lo que tengo entendido `nl2br` hace un salto de línea con `<br>`

En el JSON lo coloco así, también sustituyo el `\n` por `\r` y no funciona, no sé como representar `<br>`:

"Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde el año 1500, cuando un impresor (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró hacer un libro de textos especimen.\nNo sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de Lorem Ipsum, y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo Aldus PageMaker, el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",

Entiendo que si no están representados idénticos no hace la traducción.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi archivo app.php dentro de `./myApp/config/app.php` para elegir el el idioma en español:

```
'locale' => 'es',
```

Mi archivo es.json dentro de la carpeta `./myApp/resources/lang/es.json`:

```
{
  "paragraph": "Es es mi parrafo y es un texto largo de prueba para la comunidad de StackOverFLow. <br><br> Aquí hubo dos saltos de línea con br.",
}
```

Para que te sirva la traducción dentro de Blade deberia quedar asi:

```
<div>
  {!!__('paragraph')!!}
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]